# How do I re-tag an image in ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to follow along with [Retagging an Image with the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-retag.html) and am beginning to suspect this guide is out-of-date. I have a number of Docker images pushed into an ECR repository - let's call it "myappserver."
And so I can run commands like this one to see a list of all the images in the ECR repository:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name myappserver
```

The output I get from that command looks something like this:

```
{
    "imageDetails": [
        {
            "registryId": "123456789012",
            "repositoryName": "myappserver",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:1234...",
            "imageSizeInBytes": 33805114,
            "imagePushedAt": 1525881170.0
        },
        {
            "registryId": "123456789012",
            "repositoryName": "myappserver",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:1234...",
            "imageTags": [
                "latest"
            ],
            "imageSizeInBytes": 333805137,
            "imagePushedAt": 1525892193.0
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Because not all of my images have tags any more, I want to identify them by imageDigest (instead of imageTag like the guide does), which should be fine. However, the command that the guide offers doesn't seem to work any more. It says:

> Use the batch-get-image command to get the image manifest for the image to retag and write it to an environment variable. In this example, the manifest for an image with the tag, latest, in the repository, amazonlinux, is written to the environment variable, MANIFEST.
>
> MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --query images[].imageManifest --output text)

So, naturally, I try to run this command:

```
aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name myappserver --image-ids imageDigest=sha256:1234... --query images[].imageManifest --output text
```

But the response I get in the terminal is:

```
zsh: no matches found: images[].imageManifest
```

Interestingly enough, if I omit the last two parameters (`--query images[].imageManifest` and `--output text`) then that command does succeed and returns a bit of JSON. So I tried to copy/paste that JSON by hand into an environment variable - specifically copying the section labeled "imageManifest." Then, using that environment variable (which I've named `MANIFEST` to stay consistent with the nomenclature that the guide uses), I tried to run this command:

```
aws ecr put-image --repository-name myappserver --image-tag new-tag --image-manifest "$MANIFEST"
```

However, that results in the following error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutImage operation: Invalid parameter at 'ImageManifest' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid JSON syntax'
```

As far as I can tell, the JSON output that I copied into the `put-image` command **is valid**, despite that error. And I'm also confused why I'm unable to run the `batch-get-image` command with the provided arguments. What can I do to get these commands working, and to add tags to my image?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're getting a shell error (`zsh`) that says the wildcard expression `images[].imageManifest` didn't match any files on your local disk.

Try using quotes:

```
--query 'images[].imageManifest'
```

instead of this:

```
--query images[].imageManifest
```

Comment: Ack. Either one works as long as I add the quotes. Thanks!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686471/retagging-image-on-aws-ecr-creates-new-image/70581114#70581114

Answer (score 4):

I Just passed by the same problem.

```sh
# This script tags a untagged ECR Images using its diggest
ECR_REPO=my-ecr-repo-name
IMAGE_DIGEST="sha256:ab6DSA4f1f940df430062009fdfb02d3ede74b48e39ada939047c2e7d0ee3ac50d8"
TAG=my-tag
# ---
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name $ECR_REPO --image-ids imageDigest=$IMAGE_DIGEST --query 'images[].imageManifest' --output text)
aws ecr put-image --repository-name $ECR_REPO --image-tag $TAG --image-manifest "$MANIFEST"
```

You can see the gist:

https://gist.github.com/anderson-marques/38b802189bb8bc1cf37299cc60d653d4

Comment: It seems to create a new tag not tag an untagged image. The manifest however looks weird with a lot of \r\n's

Comment: @Teebu it worked perfectly fine for me. It did exactly what it was expected to do (tag untagged image) by providing the untagged image Digest

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat related:

The `aws ecr ... --output text` command does not preserve whitespace.
When I tried to re-tag an image, it showed up with a different digest value.

### Bad way

The following introduced carriage returns (`\r\n`) on macosx:

```bash
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --output text --query 'images[].imageManifest')
```

### Good way

This extracted the proper value, but required `jq`:

```bash
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --output json | jq --raw-output '.images[].imageManifest')
```

### Difference

```bash
... --output text --query 'images[].imageManifest'
```

vs

```bash
... --output json | jq --raw-output '.images[].imageManifest'
```

Comment: JQ seems to be the cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar error while attempting to retag an image that already had one tag.

MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --output text --query images[].imageManifest) 
[(source)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-retag.html)

Then use,

aws ecr put-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-tag $IMAGE_TAG --image-manifest "$MANIFEST" --image-manifest-media-type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json 
[(source)](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/193#issuecomment-1050910833)

Answer (score 1):

For those in windows, I needed to juggle a bit with the JSON

```
$MANIFEST = aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name REPO --image-ids "imageDigest=sha256:DIGEST" --query 'images[].imageManifest' --output json 
$x = $MANIFEST | ConvertFrom-Json
$y = $x.replace('\n', ' ').replace("`n", " ")
aws ecr put-image --repository-name REPO --image-tag 2018.12 --image-manifest "$y"
```

Comment: This didn't change anything for me
 $y = $x.replace('\n', ' ')
This worked:
   $y = $x.replace("`n", " ")

Comment: backtick n? Surprising, but i'll add it :)

Comment: Error when running your code. An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutImage operation: Invalid parameter at 'ImageManifest' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid JSON syntax' Any suggestions?

Comment: When I run $MANIFEST the terminal shows ["{\n   \"schemaVersion\": 2... and when $y, it displays {"schemaVersion": 2... Looks like API expects the JSON being put into an array brackets [] Well, adding [] didn't help either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm seems this is broken indeed. Would have to dive in.  You could try to use the file:// syntax provided in the docs. Let me know if it works! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/put-image.html

Comment: $z = $y | ConvertTo-Json, in case of a json error

Answer (score 0):

In my case the output of `aws ecr batch-get-image` was in UTF-16 LE BOM format, which `aws ecr put-image` could not digest. Converting the manifest string to UTF-8 (no BOM) in a text editor worked. Possibly this is what other answers which round-trip the string by some method are also doing, by coincidence?